# why the model file size trained by libsvm much bigger than the model file trained by opencv

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I used the same data to train a svm model,the xml model file trained by opencv is only 802 kb,but the model file trained by libsvm is bigger than 17MB; I don't know the difference between those two model file;

Comment: When you do you see in when you do the training using matrices in Matlab / Octave?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I download the source code of the libsvm and compile it in the linux. use the command line to train the model. Not in Matlab or Octave!